# Change the background color of an entire NSWindow class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm currently setting menu items to change the colours of "individual" windows in my Mac application.

```
[_window setBackgroundColor : [NSColor redColor]];
```

Is there a way to make that menu item change in all my windows, in contrast to just "_window"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `windows` method of `NSApplication`.

This would probably do it:

```
[[NSApp windows] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[NSColor redColor]];
```

(Or you might want a for-loop to examine each window more carefully.)